# How to get back to the latest version of the previous page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile

I have just setup my first jQuery Mobile website, works great, with just one flaw:
In one of my html files I have three page elements.

The first is to show filter options to get data from an internal webdatabase (WebSQL).
The second shows the results in a listview (approx. 150, 1 line each), with hyperlinks.
When clicking the hyperlinks the user goes to the third page, showing the details for the selected record, with a jqm-provided back-button.

```
$("#page2").unbind ().bind ("pagebeforeshow", function () {
  var $content = $("#page2 div:jqmData(role=content)");
  $content.html (html);
  var $ul = $content.find ("ul");
  $ul.attr("data-role", "listview");
  $ul.listview ();
});
```

This shows all records for - let's say - 3 december.
On page two I've added two buttons (previous day / next day)

Now I found a way (perhaps not the right one) to replace the data on page two with the data for the appropriate day in case the user clicks on one of the buttons. I rebuild the html with the new records and replace the old content of the div-element with new data:

```
$("#data").html (html);
```

When I'm on page 2 the first time, I can click the records, see the details (page 3) and go back to page 2. But when I move one or more days back or forth and then go to page 3, the back button still brings me back to 3 december, and not the date that I moved to.

This is probably, because I only changed the html of page 2.

How can I change this behaviour? Is there another way to go to the next day?

BTW. I can't use a pagination plugin that loads all the records and only shows a single day by hiding all the other ones, because then all records will be retrieved and building the layout for so many records takes way too much time.

Hope someone can give me a push in the right direction.

Comment: you should put the information needed to rebuild the page in the url after the hashtag, like `example.com/page1#day=monday` and read it out with `window.location.hash`

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try and let you know

Comment: You put me on the right track. It turned out I needed the hashchange: On the first page (with the filteroptions) and on the second page (with the previous/next buttons) I can use the same call, even without adding parameters to my url. `$.mobile.changePage ($("#datapage"), { allowSamePageTransition : true, reloadPage: true, changeHash: true, transition: 'none' });` Thanks again!